# How to keep track of the index in an Array.sliding

Tags: arrays, scala, sequence, sliding

When using a `sliding` function on an `Array` in scala, what is a correct way to track the index of the sliding subarray in terms of the original array?

```
// Initialize some data
val bigArray = List(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5).toArray
val n:Int = 5

// Slide through the big array
for (smallArray <- bigArray.sliding(n)) {
  val thirdValue:Int = smallArray(3)
  val k = (bigArray zip smallArray) lastIndexWhere { case (x, y) => x < y }
  if (bigArray(k+1) >= thirdValue) {
    println(bigArray.toList.toString + 
      " has "
      + bigArray(k+1)
      + " >= " 
      + thirdValue 
      + " in "
      + smallArray.toList.toString
      + " at index "
      + k+1)
  }
```

Now I know that

```
val k = (bigArray zip smallArray) lastIndexWhere { case (x, y) => x < y }
```

is incorrect. What is the correct way to track where the `smallArray` is in terms of the original `bigArray`?

What I'm getting is

```
List(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5) has 2 >= 2 in List(2, 3, 4, 2, 3) at index -11
List(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5) has 6 >= 3 in List(3, 4, 2, 3, 6) at index 41
List(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5) has 6 >= 6 in List(4, 2, 3, 6, 8) at index 41
List(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5) has 6 >= 4 in List(3, 6, 8, 4, 5) at index 41
```

and I need

```
List(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5) has 6 >= 2 in List(2, 3, 4, 2, 3) at index 5
List(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5) has 8 >= 3 in List(3, 4, 2, 3, 6) at index 6
```

**Update**

I couldn't get `map` to work with the `tuple2(Int, Int)` that came from `head` in the accepted answer, but the mention of `zipWithIndex` got me there, so I accepted the helpful answer. This is what I ended up with:

```
for (zipArray <- bigArray.slice(0, bigArray.length - 1).zipWithIndex.sliding(n)) {
  val j = zipArray.head._2
  val k = zipArray.last._2
  val smallArray = bigArray.slice(j, k)
  val thirdValue:Int = smallArray(3)
  if (bigArray(k+1) >= thirdValue) {
    println(bigArray.toList.toString +
      " has "
      + bigArray(k+1)
      + " >= "
      + thirdValue
      + " in "
      + smallArray.toList.toString
      + " at index "
      + (k+1) )
  }
}
```

which yields:

```
List(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5) has 6 >= 2 in List(2, 3, 4, 2) at index 5
List(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5) has 8 >= 3 in List(3, 4, 2, 3) at index 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zipWithIndex` before `sliding`:

```
for (smallArrayWithIndex <- bigArray.zipWithIndex.sliding(n)) {
    val startingIndex = smallArrayWithIndex.head.map { case (_, index) => index }
    val smallArray = smallArrayWithIndex.map { case (e, _) => e }
    println("smallArray starts at index " + index + " and contains " + smallArray)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What do I need to do to allow the standard `map` to act on `smallArrayWithIndex.head` which is `(Int, Int)`.

Comment: I couldn't get `map` to resolve, but your help with `zipWithIndex` got me there in the end. Thanks.